# CGO how to convert to a FILE* type

Tags: go, stdio, cgo

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_string( FILE *stream, char *text) {
    printf("Input pointer is %p\n", (void *) stream);
    printf("Expected stderr is %p\n", (void *) stderr);
    fprintf(stream, text);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    text := C.CString("test123\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))

    // fileStream := (*C.FILE)(C.stderr) // this works
    fileStream := (*C.FILE)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(syscall.Stderr)))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(fileStream))

    C.print_string(fileStream, text)
}
```

Throws an access violation exception.

I'm wanting to do this because a C library I want to use fprintf's the errors so I want to be able to create a Go file to read the errors from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do

```golang
(*C.FILE)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(syscall.Stderr)))
```

For two reasons:

- `syscall.Stderr` is system-dependent: on UNIX-like systems (including macOS) it's merely an integer number (2), while on Windows it's a `HANDLE` (which can as well be `NULL` if the application is not attached to a console, but we digress).
- A `FILE*` is a (pointer to a) type provided by the C standard library, and Go does not use it to work with files.

So there's simply no way to type-convert (or type cast, if you like) `syscall.Stderr` to a `FILE*`. The fact you've defeated the Go's type system using the usual tricks so that the attempted conversion compiles means nothing: your code basically makes a pointer (an address of memory) with the value 2, and if this happens on x86, you merely get an expected fault when attempting to read memory at address 0x02. On different platforms it may have more funny results but I think you get the idea.

But then the question is: why want that?
Depending on what you're after, you have three options:

- You might want to print to stderr from C code linked to your Go code, you can merely use the `stderr` symbol provided by the C standard library and directly call `fprintf` et al on it.
- You might want to obtain a file descriptor out of `os.Stderr` by calling `os.Stderr.Fd()` and then doing `fdopen(3)` on the returned FD at the C side.
- You might want to use `os.Stderr` (which is not the same thing as `syscall.Stderr`!) for output sort-of directly from the C side. To do that, you have to write and provide to your C side a set of wrapper Go functions.

Note that the first two options above would not provide any synchronization with the Go side. I mean, if it's possible for your C code and your Go code to write to the process' stderr from different threads in parallel, you might get intermixed output.

They also do not protect from Go code reopening `os.Stderr` to another file while *not* managing to have that new file reuse the standard stderr's file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks yea, I found the issue with the handle and knew about os.Stderr being different, I thought that `FILE*` was just a pointer to a file descriptor, but I guess that's not true.  Thanks though!  I think the only good solution is `fdopen` and I don't want to write to stderr simultaneously, instead I want the C code to write to some kind of stream or even temp file, and the Go code just reads that and returns an error

Comment: @Aidan, „`FILE*` was just a pointer to a file descriptor, but I guess that's not true”–absolutely not true as at the very minimum stdlib provides three selectable levels of buffering of `FILE*`s (none, line and full), and libc on non-UNIX platforms also differentiates between "text" and "binary" files; all those things require certain state kept aside of an FD, and I think you see where I'm leading to ;-)

Comment: Also this seems to be roughly Win32 equivalent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?view=msvc-170

Comment: But then of course you'd need to fdopen that

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to do it in Windows and Linux:

Windows:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void print_string( FILE *stream, char *text) {
    printf("Input is %d\n", fileno(stream));
    printf("Expected stderr is %d\n", fileno(stderr));
    fprintf(stream, text);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    text := C.CString("test123\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))

    handle := C.longlong(syscall.Stderr)
    fd := C._open_osfhandle(handle, C._O_WRONLY)

    fileStream := C._fdopen(fd, C.CString("w"))
    defer C.fclose(fileStream)

    C.print_string(fileStream, text)
}
```

And Linux:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_string( FILE *stream, char *text) {
    printf("Input is %d\n", fileno(stream));
    printf("Expected stderr is %d\n", fileno(stderr));
    fprintf(stream, text);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    text := C.CString("test123\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))

    fd := C.int(syscall.Stderr)

    fileStream := C.fdopen(fd, C.CString("w"))
    defer C.fclose(fileStream)

    C.print_string(fileStream, text)
}
```

And here is how I did that with pipes for windows:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void print_string( FILE *stream, char *text) {
    fprintf(stream, "%s\n", text);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

func listenToPipe(reader *os.File, response chan error) {
    b, err := io.ReadAll(reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    log.Printf("read: %v\n", string(b[:]))

    response <- nil
}

func main() {
    text := C.CString("foobar\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))

    pipeReaderFile, pipeWriterFile, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    handle := C.longlong(pipeWriterFile.Fd())
    fd := C._open_osfhandle(handle, C._O_WRONLY)

    writerCFile := C._fdopen(fd, C.CString("w"))

    ch := make(chan error)

    go listenToPipe(pipeReaderFile, ch)
    C.print_string(writerCFile, text)
    C.fclose(writerCFile)
    pipeWriterFile.Close()
    <-ch
    pipeReaderFile.Close()
}
```

and posix:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_string( FILE *stream, char *text) {
    fprintf(stream, "%s\n", text);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

func listenToPipe(reader *os.File, response chan error) {
    b, err := io.ReadAll(reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    log.Printf("read: %v\n", string(b[:]))

    response <- nil
}

func main() {
    text := C.CString("foobar\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(text))

    pipeReaderFile, pipeWriterFile, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    writerCFile := C.fdopen(C.int(pipeWriterFile.Fd()), C.CString("w"))

    ch := make(chan error)

    go listenToPipe(pipeReaderFile, ch)
    C.print_string(writerCFile, text)
    C.fclose(writerCFile)
    pipeWriterFile.Close()
    <-ch
    pipeReaderFile.Close()
}
```